# Dynamic image height in tableview not working for initial few cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**I am trying to make dynamic image height in tableview. i used SDWebImage to download image from URL. but it's not working on few initial cell**

Here below methods that i wrote

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {       
    let shareDetailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: THShareDetailTableViewCell.className, for: indexPath) as! THShareDetailTableViewCell
                    shareDetailCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
                    shareDetailCell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row

            //to set image dynamic height
    shareDetailCell.selectionStyle.socialPostImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: socialInteraction[indexpath.row].largeImageUrl), placeholderImage: nil, options: .retryFailed) { (image, error, imageCacheType, imageUrl) in
                    if image != nil {
                        let imgHeight = (image?.size.height)!
                       shareDetailCell.heightConstraintSocialImage.constant = (imgHeight * (self.socialPostImage.frame.size.width/imgHeight))
                    }else {
                        print("image not found")
                    }
                }
                    return shareDetailCell
            }
```

Comment: Could you share an example of what your result and what you are expecting? Watching your code the error seems to be in the method `heightForRowAt indexPath` you should give the height calculated

Comment: So the problem seems to be when you download the image, the cell doesn't update. I assume when you scroll down and back up to the cell then the height is correct

Comment: @Devster101  same problem as you said. what is solution to update that cell after downlod image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code work I found two things ,

1. Never return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` from `estimatedHeightForRowAt` because estimated height is never be Automatic otherwise x-code does not understand what height it should need to return. Sometimes it works but not considered as a good practice.
2. You fetching the Images in the `cellForRowAt` method that means upto you fetch the image the height of cell is already set. So your cell images that height only.`UITableViewAutomaticDimension` works when system knows the height of that cell at the `heightForRowAt` method not after that.

> Suggestion for your problem.

Once you fetch the data and then reload your `tableView` so that cell height is adjusted according to the image height. You can do this in paging also.